# Kubernetes Ingress Controller with private IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

is it possible to deploy an ingress controller (nginx) without a public ip address?

Thanks!

Comment: @sokolata-- what cloud provider are you using and which ingress controller are you referring to?

Answer (score 6):

> is it possible to deploy an ingress controller (nginx) without a public ip address?

Without question, yes, if the Ingress controller's `Service` is of `type: NodePort` then the Ingress controller's private IP address is **every** `Node`'s IP address, on the port(s) pointing to `:80` and `:443` of the `Service`. Secretly, that's exactly what is happening anyway with `type: LoadBalancer`, just with the extra sugar coating of the cloud provider mapping between the load balancer's IP address and the binding to the `Node`'s ports.

So, to close that loop: if you wished to have a 100% internal Ingress controller, then use a `hostNetwork: true` and bind the Ingress controller's `ports:` to be the **host**'s port 80 and 443; then, make a DNS (A record|CNAME record) for each virtual-host that resolve to the address of every `Node` in the cluster, and poof: 100% non-Internet-facing Ingress controller.

Comment: you can also expose the nginx-controller service as type LoadBalancer with an internal IP if your cloud provider supports it, such as GCP

Comment: @PatrickW  I am looking for something similar. Would you please tell more about this approach? Is it an annotation or helm variable in the stable chart or editing the yaml files directly?

Comment: On GCP, you add an [annotation to the service type LoadBalancer, cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "internal"](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing). You'll need to recreate the service though, you can't edit the service already in place

Comment: Thanks. This command `helm install stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.annotations."cloud\.google\.com/load-balancer-type"="Internal"` worked for me :)

Comment: @mdaniel : would really appreciate a concrete example.

Answer (score 3):

### Internal IP ingress in Google Kubernetes Engine

Assuming you wanna *deploy an ingress controller (nginx) without a public ip address* in GKE. Below is what worked for me.

#### 1. Install Nginx-Ingress controller with appropriate annotations

Use [stable/nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) helm chart to install [ingress-nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) in out GKE cluster.

As per this [GCP document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) we can create a Load Balancer resource with `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` annotation to create an internal Load Balancer. Run the below command to add the controller to GKE.

```sh
helm install --name ingress-controller stable/nginx-ingress \
--set controller.service.annotations."cloud\.google\.com/load-balancer-type"="Internal"
```

#### 2. Deploy ingress resources using this controller

To make Ingress resources use the controller, add the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation to your ingress resources.

An example Ingress resource using nginx-ingress controller looks something like below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: nginx-test
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: my-service-1
            servicePort: 80
          path: /tasks
        - backend:
            serviceName: my-service-2
            servicePort: 80
          path: /
```

Now using `kubectl` command you can see the assigned IP to your ingress resource is an internal IP address.

#### 3. In case you wanna use TLS too (Optional)

Add the below to your YAML manifest:

```
  ...
  rules:
  ...
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: my-certs
```

In the above example `my-certs` is a Kubernetes secret containing the server key, certificate and CA certificate created using the below command:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic my-certs --from-file=tls.crt=server.crt --from-file=tls.key=server.key --from-file=ca.crt=ca.crt
```

For an example above keys and certificates are created with a sample hostname referring to this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@awkwardferny/configuring-certificate-based-mutual-authentication-with-kubernetes-ingress-nginx-20e7e38fdfca).

Hope this helps.