# kubernetes ingress IP keeps alternating from private to public

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up an ingress controller in GKE.

However out of the sudden, a couple of days ago I noticed some inconsistency in my service.

I then realised that in the following command I keep getting alternate results in terms of private vs public ip

```
▶ k get ingress -A
NAMESPACE   NAME         CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
myns     something   <none>   *       10.1.111.123   80      295d
[19/04/21 1:12:28]
~/Desktop
▶ k get ingress -A
NAMESPACE   NAME         CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
myns     something   <none>   *       234.98.11.198   80      295d
```

what is this?

**edit**:
I am using an `nginx` ingress controller as installed from the deprecated chart.

Here is the spec

```
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-cd
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /jenkins
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.1.34.201
```

For some reason the `status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip` kept alternating between a public and a private ip.

Ιs there a reason that at any point this could/should point to a public ip?

Comment: Are you using [GKE Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) or [NGINX Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) ? 
Can you provide your Ingress resource manifest file ?

Comment: Check my update on the question

Comment: How did you install the `nginx-ingress` ?
Did you use the appropriate annotation as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280543/14801225) ?
Can you check the `load balancing scheme` of your load balancer ?